# WaitHandle.WaitAll not waiting?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delegates

I've got a console application that I am trying to do some threading work with, using .NET 3.5.

```
    int[] iArrReports = { 6/*, 103*/ };
    WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[iArrReports.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < iArrReports.Length; i++)
    {
      PerformMergeDelegate mergeDelegate = new PerformMergeDelegate(doWork);
      IAsyncResult result = mergeDelegate.BeginInvoke(iArrReports[i], (r) =>
      {
        Logger delegateLogger = mergeDelegate.EndInvoke(r);
        if (delegateLogger.iMessageLevel == Logger.LOG_LEVELS.LEVEL_ERROR)
        {
          try
          {
            Monitor.Enter(logger);
            logger.LogFile(delegateLogger.strErrorMessage);
          }
          finally
          {
            Monitor.Exit(logger);
          }
        }
      }, null);
      handles[i] = result.AsyncWaitHandle;
    }
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);
```

When I step through the code in VS2013, I have a breakpoint set in my `doWork` method that is getting hit, but shortly after it is hit the `WaitAll` seems to return and the application closes. I commented out the second entry in `iArrReports` just for testing.

Why is my application closing? I thought the `WaitAll` was supposed to wait until the delegate executed completely.

Comment: This methods does wait, yes. Set your debugger to break on all exceptions. Better yet, use Tasks or Parallel.ForEach and the lock statement.

Comment: Looks like I was hitting an exception in my delegate that I didn't handle, I didn't even think it would be something so simple :) please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your debugger to break on all exceptions. You'll probably find that an unhandled exception has killed the process.

Better use the TPL. Would have prevented this mistake.